# Style input radio from JS quiz

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have a quiz executed from a JS. It is an array of a 100 question pool. Every attempt just 5 questions are displayed, that is why I am doing this way. I want to style its radio buttons. I am doing as follows and it is not working:

JavaScript:

```
  answers.push(
      `<label class="quiz">
        <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
        ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
      </label>`
    );
```

CSS:

```
.quiz input[type="radio"] {
   display: none;
}
.quiz label {
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: red;
   padding: 4px 11px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 16px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.quiz input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: I am trying to change the style of the radio buttons and it is not working :s

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are simply trying to apply styles to the element `<label class="quiz">`. If so, you have the CSS selector in the incorrect order.

To apply the style to the element `label` with class `quiz`, you should write the selector as `label.quiz`

`.quiz label` will look for `label` elements that are children of an element with class `quiz`

If I've misunderstood your question please let me know :)

Comment: I tried as you said, but it it not working either. Look: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQyeGW
I just want to style the radio buttons.

Comment: @AntonioAndrés I noticed that you added a `.` to `label` in your CSS. The `.` is a class selector and will not apply to the element `label`. See your slightly altered Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYRxPb

Comment: Thanks Frish, I see what you mean, but the radio buttons are the same. Would like to change its style, I guess I am doing something wrong :s

Comment: @AntonioAndrés a few days late perhaps, but after a quick google I found something that might interest you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: I had a look a it as well, but I couldn't figure out why it was not working. I guess it is because the questions are coming from a JS instead from an HTML. Anyways, finally I am using the Onsen UI framework and it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

your label is malformed.

```
answers.push(
    `<input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
    <label class="quiz">${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}</label>`
);
```

and remove .label from 2 css declarations:

```
.quiz {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 4px 11px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

i don't think you want this (remove):

```
/*.label.quiz input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}*/
```

change:

```
.answers label{
    display: inline-block;
    ...
```

https://codepen.io/wazz/pen/paPaEN

Comment: Now I can change the style of the text's part, but I would like to change the radio buttons style. Another point: for mobile resolution the radio button is displayed after the answers instead of before (left-side). Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The style of radio buttons is built in to each browser and can't be changed afaik.

Comment: Finally I am using the Onsen UI framework and it is working fine :)